# AS3 ByteArray with multiple parts

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays

I'm thinking about distributing bytes of a SWF into multiple files, how can i put a set of bytes in different parts into one byte array?

E.G:

```
var bytesPartOne:ByteArray;
var bytesPartTwo:ByteArray;
var bytesPartThree:ByteArray;
var bytesPartFour:ByteArray;
```

Into one byte array?

```
var totalBytes:ByteArray;
```

Also would reading partial bytes into a byte array work?

Comment: may ask you to tell more about the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Into one byte array?

```
var totalBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
totalBytes.writeBytes(bytesPartOne);
totalBytes.writeBytes(bytesPartTwo);
totalBytes.writeBytes(bytesPartThree);
totalBytes.writeBytes(bytesPartFour);
```

Note : Be sure that bytesPartOne/two/Three/Four have position set to zero (can be done by bytesPartOne.position = 0, ...)

> Also would reading partial bytes into a byte array work?

What do you mean by partial bytes ?